# How do I secure fields on a Firestore document when allowing update?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Using Firebase Firestore I am storing chat room details in documents containing some data like:

```
roomName
roomAvatar
createDate
isDeleted
```

My application and my rules are requiring these fields to be set on "create" of the document.  However, I would also like to allow the document to be "updated" by authorized users as well.

I already have the checks working to only allow certain users the ability to update the document and verify that they NOT be allowed to modify a field like "createDate".  But, I cannot seem to create a rule that enforces an authorized user doesn't remove the "createDate" field, either by passing FiledValue.delete() or using ref.set(objectMissingCreateDate).

Lastly, I don't think it should be required that the client pass in all data fields on an update if they are only trying to update one or two fields.

I have an "update" rule as follows:

```
allow update: if isAuthenticated() && isMemberOfRoom() && 
  (
    (!("roomName" in request.resource.data) || 
      request.resource.data.roomName == resource.data.roomName || 
      hasRoomPermission("UpdateRoom")) &&
    (!("roomAvatar" in request.resource.data) || 
      request.resource.data.roomAvatar == resource.data.roomAvatar || 
      hasRoomPermission("UpdateRoom")) &&
    (!("createDate" in request.resource.data) || 
      request.resource.data.createDate == resource.data.createDate) &&
    (!("isDeleted" in request.resource.data) || 
      request.resource.data.isDeleted == resource.data.isDeleted || 
      hasRoomPermission("DeleteRoom"))
  );
```

The main issue is protecting the data from an authorized user passing in FieldValue.delete() or using the [Android] docRef.set() while missing required values.

I would even accept the functionality to turn off FieldValue.delete() and destructive "set" operations for non-admin clients.

Comment: By my experimentation with the Firestore rules emulator, simply saying `allow write: if "foo" in request.resource.data;` allows partial updates that don't specify foo when it previously existed, and defends against `{foo: FieldValue.delete()}`.

Comment: "I don't think it should be required that the client pass in all data fields on an update if they are only trying to update one or two fields." They don't have to do that. The `request.resource` contains the values as they will be if the update is allowed. So if the document contains 3 fields of which one is updated, `request.resource` contains the 3 fields as they'll be if the update is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on the way data is evaluated within the rules flow.  I have added an answer to my question that seems to be working.  I really appreciate the fast responses of the Firebase team!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Doug and Puff's comments, I realize what I was doing wrong.

First, I was not aware that an update (or a set with merge options) that passed only a few fields, would result in the remaining fields being copied on the `request.resource` from the database's `resource`.

Second, a set (without merge) or passing in a `FieldValue.delete()` would be the only way that the `request.resource` would be missing an existing document field.

With this new knowledge, I have updated my previous rules to the following:

```
allow update: if isAuthenticated() && isMemberOfRoom() && 
  (
    ("roomName" in request.resource.data && 
      (request.resource.data.roomName == resource.data.roomName || 
      hasRoomPermission("UpdateRoom"))) &&
    ("roomAvatar" in request.resource.data && 
      (request.resource.data.roomAvatar == resource.data.roomAvatar || 
      hasRoomPermission("UpdateRoom"))) &&
    ("createDate" in request.resource.data && 
      request.resource.data.createDate == resource.data.createDate) &&
    ("isDeleted" in request.resource.data && 
      (request.resource.data.isDeleted == resource.data.isDeleted || 
      hasRoomPermission("DeleteRoom")))
  );
```

These new rules now make `createDate` locked for clients, while allowing the editing of `roomName`, `roomAvatar`, and `isDeleted` for clients who pass the permission test(s).  It will also not allow any of these fields to be updated with `FieldValue.delete()` or calling `docRef.set(object)` where the object is missing one of these fields.